# save data in database without redirection in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple form, and I want to save the data in my database without redirection. I am using php, ajax and jquery for my page. I don't know if I did something wrong but after I hit the submit button the form data appears on the address bar. the data is stored in the database successfully but the page reloads as well. My code is given below.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Full Name*" required pattern= "[a-zA-Z]+" title="Alphabets only" name="name" id="name">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email*" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" name="email" id="email">
<input type="text" placeholder="Contact*" required pattern="[0-9]\d{9}" title="only 10 digit allowed" name="contact" id="contact">
<textarea placeholder="Enquiry(if any)" name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="register" id="register_btn">Register</button>
<span id="success"></span>
<span id="error"></span>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
    include("conn/connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
    $contact= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contact']);
    $msg= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['msg']);
    $sql= "INSERT INTO registration(email, name, contact, msg, added_on) values('$email','$name','$contact','$msg', now())";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
    {
        echo '<h4>Registration Complete</h4>';
    }
```

}

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#register_btn').click(function(){  
  var name = $('#name').val();  
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var contact = $('#contact').val();
  var msg = $('#msg').val();  
  if(name == '' || email == '' || contact == '')  
  {  
      $('#error').html("<h4>Mandatory field(s) are empty</h4>");
      setTimeout(function(){  
          $('#error').fadeOut("Slow");  
          }, 3000);  
        }  
  else  
      {  
        $('#error').html('');  
        $.ajax({  
           url:"registration.php",  
           type:"POST",  
           data:{name:name, email:email, contact:contact, msg:msg},  
           success:function(data){  
           $("form").trigger("reset");  
           $('#success').fadeIn().html(data);  
           setTimeout(function(){  
              $('#success').fadeOut("Slow");  
             }, 3000);  
           }  
        });  
     }  
   });  
  });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling an event on `submit` button that will refresh your page.

Use `event.preventDefault()` in your click function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#register_btn').click(function(event){  
     event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

FYI, if your validations stop working then try to do this.

```
$('#register_btn').click(function(event) {
  //Check form is valid
  if ($(this).closest('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    // stop form from redirecting to java servlet page
    event.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr("method"), // use method specified in form attributes
      url: form.attr("action"), // use action specified in form attributes
      data: form.serialize(), // encodes set of form elements as string for submission
      success: function(data) {
        // get response from servlet and display on page via jQuery 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @ratulkeot no problem, glad to help.

Comment: But then no form validation is done as suggested by provided HTML markup. It should be: `if($(this).closest('form')[0].checkValidity()) event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for drawing my attention, I've updated my answer to check form is valid or not.

Comment: But it won't work the way it should :) BTW, what is `valid()`?

Comment: `.valid()` a method to check form is valid or not. to call validation check for validations jquery plugin. I just shown him a way. He never raised a problem of validation till now.

Comment: What you're suggesting on this ?

Comment: I edited previous comment, maybe you missed it but to get the HTML5 form validation to work as expected (not any jQuery validation plugin), you need to prevent submit behaviour only if form is valid: `if($(this).closest('form')[0].checkValidity()) event.preventDefault();`  See example there: https://jsfiddle.net/vda4m4L9/

Answer (score 0):

As Loading.. points out you need event prevent default but in the form submit event, like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

return false on submit = e.preventDefault + e.sotpPropagation